# Time based cookie(created in java servlet) is not getting deleted from the browser automatically after the time out

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I have a requirement to create a time based cookie in java servlets. 
Time based Cookie is created in servlet with 10 mins time duration.
The cookie is not getting deleted/removed from cookies list in the browser(Firefox,Chrome)

Can anyone tell me how to delete the cookie from the browser automatically after time out?

thanks in advance.

Comment: you cannot, the browser is free to delete or not delete.

Comment: we are at the mercy of the browsers. why not just use a session cookie if the expiration time is so small?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. My actual requirement is to redirect the user to login page if the user is idle on any page for 10 mins. There are some other session cookie which will be deleted based on this time based cookie and user would be redirected to login page. Please provide any suggesions reg this.

Answer (score 0):

In your servlet you can setMaxAge(0), make sure you don't forget to addCookie to the response after setting the max age to 0.